# what the Conv1D with kernel size equal to 1 do?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, convolution

I read an example of using `LSTM` with `CONV1`.
(Took it from: [CNN LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/))

```
Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')
```

- I understand that the dimension of the convolutional  is 1 (one dim with size 1))

1. what is the value of the convolution ? (what is the value of the matrix 1*1 ?)
2. I can't figure out what is the `filters=64` ? what does it mean ?
3. Is the `relu` activation function work on the output of the convolutional ? (from what I read it seems like that, but I'm not sure)
4. what is the motivation to use convolutional with `kernel_size = 1`, as we do here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### filters

`filters = 64` means number of separate filters used is 64.
Each filter will output 1 channel. i.e. here 64 filters operate on input to produce 64 different channels(or vectors). Hence `filters` parameter determines number of output channels.

#### kernel_size

`kernel_size` determines the size of the convolution window. Suppose `kernel_size = 1` then each kernel will have dimension of `in_channels x 1`. Hence each kernel weight will be `in_channels x 1` dimension tensor.

#### activation = relu

That means `relu` activation will be applied on the output of convolution operation.

#### kernel_size = 1 convolution

Used to reduce depth channels with applying non-linearity. It will do something like weighted average across the channels while keeping receptive field.

In your eg: `filters = 64, kernel_size = 1, activation = relu`
Suppose input feature map has size of `100 x 10`(100 channels). Then the layer weight will of dimension `64 x 100 x 1`. The output size will be `64 x 10`.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the value of the convolution ? (for example blue convolution of 3x3 contains 9 values of 1/9). what is the value here of the convolution ?

Comment: Suppose input vector is [[1,1,1], [2,2,2]] i.e 2 channel vector with length 3 and kernels are [[.5], [.5]] and [[1], [1]] then output will be [[1.5, 1.5, 1.5], [3, 3, 3]] (bcoz 1x0.5 + 2x0.5 = 1.5 and 1x1 + 2x1 = 3)

Comment: Default kernel initialization method in keras will be glorot_uniform.

Comment: I guess I miss something in your example. if the kernel are [[.5], [.5]]  and [[.5], [.5]] then the kernel_size is not 1 ? (it's 1*2 no?)

Comment: Kernel_ size = 1 means size of kernel's spacial(1st) dimension will be 1. Here 2nd dimension represent channels which depends on input feature channel size. Check [this](https://youtu.be/vcp0XvDAX68) video about 1x1 convolution