# I want to understand strcutre of Conv2D in machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am  learning AI. while doing the course I came across *cov2D* concept.
as per defination this is what i have understood.

In 3rd line after `Conv2D` they mentioned `16,(3,3)`  which means the image is processed  through *16 filters(matrix)* which has a dimension of *3,3*.

My question is: in input we are feeding image with *300*300* matrix to.  How  *300*300* image will be able to filterout through *3*3* filter of *conv2D*?

```
#Note the input shape is the desired size of the image 300x300 with 3 bytes color
#This is the first convolution
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(300, 300, 3)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
# The second convolution
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
```

Comment: **convolution** operation itself means that **sliding** a fixed size **kernel** over feature maps and taking **dot product** at every step to produce output(i.e parameter sharing).sO 3x3 filter is enough

Comment: check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63445097/14108734) answer it may help.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider reading this

https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-introduction-to-convolutional-neural-networks-cdf8d3077bac